# How do I control pausing/playing with videos in a carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flickity

I have a video carousel created using the [flickity carousel library](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/), seen [here on codepen](http://codepen.io/np20/pen/vKQmoj). What I want to happen is that when a user slides the carousel, the selected slide stops playing, then the slide that takes the selected, middle position starts to play. Right now, using jQuery, I get the selected slide to initially play:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var $partnerSlides = $('.partner-slides').flickity();

       function onLoadeddata(event) {
           var cell = $partnerSlides.flickity('getParentCell', event.target);
                $partnerSlides.flickity('cellSizeChange', cell && cell.element);
       }

       $partnerSlides.find('.slide video').each(function (i, video) {
           video.pause();
           $(video).on('durationchange', onLoadeddata);
       });

       $partnerSlides.find('.slide.is-selected video').each(function (i, video) {
           video.play();
           $(video).on('durationchange', onLoadeddata);
       });

});
```

But when the slides switch position, the selected slide just moves position and keeps playing, while the new slide takes the middle position and doesn't play.

Is there a way to update those functions each time the carousel slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out what I thought is the best way to do this. There is an event for the carousel, `'settle.flickity'`, which fires each time the carousel settles after being slid or autoplayed (More can be read about the `flickity` events [here on flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/events.html). Therefore, this code:

```
var $gallery = $('.partner-slides').flickity(); //this is the carousel

  $gallery.on('settle.flickity', function () {
      console.log('Flickity settled at ' + flkty.selectedIndex);

      $gallery.find('.slide video').each(function (i, video) {
          video.pause();
          $(video).on('loadeddata', onLoadeddata);
      });

      $gallery.find('.slide.is-selected video').each(function (i, video) {
          video.play();
          $(video).on('loadeddata', onLoadeddata);
      });

  });
```

Will play the selected video and pause any video that is not selected.